# RMI: ServerException, RemoteException, UnmarshalException, UnmarshalException

Tags: java, exception, rmi

I followed this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html#5

I compiled them at command prompt and after that I started rmiregistry. Then, after I typed:

```
    start java -classpath "." example.Server
```

it didn't show "Server ready." But, it didn't display any errors as well.

While when I tried it at Eclipse, it showed this:

```
  Server exception: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example.Hello
    java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example.Hello
```

Hello.java

```
   package example;

   import java.rmi.Remote;
   import java.rmi.RemoteException;

   public interface Hello extends Remote
   {
        String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
   }
```

Server.java

```
    package example;

    import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
    import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;
    import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

     public class Server implements Hello
    {

           public Server() {}

           public String sayHello()
           {
           return "Hello, world!";
           }

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        Server obj = new Server();
        Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);

        // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        registry.bind("Hello", stub);

        System.err.println("Server ready");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Client.java

```
   package example;

   import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
   import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

   public class Client 
   {

        private Client() {}

       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {

            String host = (args.length < 1) ? null : args[0];
            try {
                  Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
                  Hello stub = (Hello) registry.lookup("Hello");
                  String response = stub.sayHello();
                  System.out.println("response: " + response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Client exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
   }
```

Are there any steps that I missed? What should I do?

Comment: The RMI Registry could not find your application classes. You need to start with a classpath argument.

Answer (score -1):

`ClassNotFoundException: example.Hello` - your application does not find this class. Add this class to the class path, both to the client and to the server.

If you launch your client on some other PC than Sserver, don't forget to copy your class `example.Hello` together with your client.

Comment: The *Registry* could not find this class.

Comment: @user207421: It **is ** started with classpath. Obviously, the class is missing in that class path of the Client. You can launch it and will get this exception. Strange that you are downvoting a correct answer.

Comment: @mentallurg How can I do that? Do I replace -classpath with the classpath of the client? I really don't understand.

Comment: @PartaCanna: Tell us in what directory you are trying to launch Server and Client, in what diretory are your classes, also check if you really have class files there.

Comment: Read what I wrote. The Registry is throwing the exception, and *it* needs to be started with a CLASSPATH argument (or in the directory containing the root package directory), and there is nothing in the question that indicates that it is. The OP is getting a `ServerException`, which is a `RemoteException` thrown by the server, *in his own server*, which acts as a client only to the RMI Registry, so it is therefore the Registry that threw the exception, so it is therefore the Registry that can't find the class. Strange that you have information about voting here, which is secret.

Comment: @mentallurg Directories of Server and Client: C:\Users\Admin\eclipse-workspace\HelloRMI\src\example\Server.java. Directories of classes: C:\Users\Admin\eclipse-workspace\HelloRMI\bin\example\Server.class .I also noticed that there's a certain note called classpath, which has this:                 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre1.8.0_221"/>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>